# MVC - Unable to call my model in my view

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

i created a model as the below in my model folder

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;

namespace EMWeb.Models
{
    public class ReportIndexModel
    {
        public ObjectResult<GetTxSummary_Result> txSummaryResult { get; set; }
    }
}
```

However, in my view, it appeared this,
[image]

may i know how to solve this?

Comment: First remove the `;` at the end. And you may need the fully qualified name of the class - `@model EMWeb.Models.ReportIndexModel`

Comment: @StephenMuecke hi it is same, and i can call this model on my controller but view

Comment: You need to remove the `;`

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the reference of model like

```
@model EMWeb.Models.ReportIndexModel
```

no need to put `;` just remove it.